# Recursively list all files and subdirectories with modified timestamp

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell-script, bash-scripting

In a Unix Shell you can use the following to print a list of all files and subfolders recursively:

```
cd some/path/to/folder
du -a
```

and you can list file information (such as permissions and timestamps) with the following:

```
stat filename.ext
```

Is there a way you can combine the commands to list all the files and subfolders of a directory recursively (with relative path) followed by the modified time? For example:

```
a_file.txt: 06/27/19 - 08:34:16
a_subfolder: 07/30/18 - 18:23:14
```

Bonus: Something that will work for both Linux and OSX, and output to a txt file

Comment: Does your `find` support `-printf`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I believe it works, would prefer commands that work in a generic Unix Shell (so that it works for both OS X and Linux)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide a format to `stat`: `stat -c '%n: %y' somefile` will print the name and last modification time of `somefile` (`%n` actually replicates the parameter passed as a filename).

`find [...search parameters...] -exec somecommand {} \;` iterates alld files and directories and executes `somecommand` on every file/directory that matches, passing the file/directory name as a parameter.

Putting it all together:

```
find . -exec stat -c "%n: %y" {} \;
```

... will iterate all the files and directories under the current directory, and print their name and last modification date.

Comment: Brilliant, that did the trick!

Comment: Invalid command -c"

stat: illegal option -- c

On mac

Comment: @BerlinBrown You are missing a space between `-c` and the double quote (you entered `-c"%n: %y"` and not `-c "%n: %y"`)